# Read XML file and get XML element as String - SAX

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I have a specific requirement where I need to read large XQL file (say 5GB to 10GB). I must not use DOM parser as this is huge file. I am amusing there should be generic solution for this but not able to find out.

```
<Query>
   <Question1>...</Question1>
   <Question2>...</Question2>
   ...
   <QuestionN>...</QuestionN>
<Query>
```

In the above some important attributes are there to read from `<Query>` tag. And after that I need to read tags as string list [The current working implementation is in DOM] 
Example :

```
String q1="<Question1>...</Question1>"
```

**Questions**

1) Using Java SAX, I can get values and attributes from the XML files, Is there any way to get element as XML string?

2) Do I need to write my own code to achieve this?

Comment: Can you serialize those tags into a string ? You need to write your own code to do this... is 5~10GB file a single one?

Comment: I cannot serialize tags to string, Yes the the single file is more than 5GB